# How come parseInt wont convert to base 60?

Tags: javascript

[The documentation specifies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) that the first arg in `parseInt` is the number you want mutated and the second arg is the base you want to convert it to. But when I try to use it as such it returns `NaN` instead of an integer. Why is this?

```
parseInt(65, 60)
>>>NaN
```

Comment: The documentation also says the radix must be an integer between 2 and 36.

Comment: Because 60 is not a valid radix value.. from the doc `An integer between 2 and 36 that represents the radix`

Comment: Use 10 instead of 60 as radix.
And 60 is not a correct base
Examples:
parseInt(" 0xF", 16);
parseInt(" F", 16);
parseInt("17", 8);
parseInt(021, 8);
parseInt("015", 10);
parseInt(15.99, 10);
parseInt("FXX123", 16);
parseInt("1111", 2);
parseInt("15*3", 10);
parseInt("15e2", 10);
parseInt("15px", 10);
parseInt("12", 13);

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is answered by the very reference linked.

Comment: Use base 30 and then transform the string into your desired output by mapping pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2

```
Step 8a: 
           If R < 2 or R > 36, then return NaN.
```

That's why.

<strike>It's just a arbitrary rule to simplify implementation, probably.</strike>

Edit: see comment for the probable reason.

Comment: I don't think it's arbitrary. 10 numerals + 26 letters = 36 characters to use for a base.

Comment: Ah, nice. Didn't think of that, that's probably it.

Comment: It always makes me sad there isn't a special case for base64, 26 upper case + 26 lower case + 10 numbers + "+" + "/" = 64 characters

Comment: Why stopping at 64 then? Just for the roundness of the number? Let's use all printable ascii character, that's probably in the order of 200. All the written text in any given page could then be interpreted as a single, humongous number in an improbably high radix.

Comment: @PaulS. There's a different function for that: [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa) and [atob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/atob).

Comment: @Scimonster those only work with _String_, i.e. `atob(btoa(4)); // "4" !== 4` and it's much longer because you're storing the unicode, `NA==` vs `E`

Comment: @A.Rama Base64 is a commonly used one because it fits on a nice alphabet and works well for binary: `64` is `2**6`, if you used `128 === 2**7` that is the whole _ASCII_ space including control characters like `NUL`, `EOT` and `DEL`